# Why doesn't my udev rule work?

Tags: ubuntu, audio, udev, pci

I created a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/60.alsa.rules` with the following content:

```
KERNEL=="0000:00:1b.0", SUBSYSTEM=="pci", ATTR{label}=="Realtek High Definition Audio Device", ATTR{vendor}=="0x8086", SYMLINK+="jumanji"
```

Then I restarted udev using init.d but the symbolic link `/dev/jumanji` was not created.

What should I do?

Additional information:

```
udevadm info -a -n /dev/snd/by-path/pci-0000\:00\:1b.0

looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/controlC0':
    KERNEL=="controlC0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="sound"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0':
    KERNELS=="card0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="sound"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{id}=="PCH"
    ATTRS{number}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:1b.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="snd_hda_intel"
    ATTRS{irq}=="45"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x8086"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x040300"
    ATTRS{index}=="1"
    ATTRS{label}=="Realtek High Definition Audio Device"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="ff"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x1c20"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}==""
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-7"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x2042"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

Comment: Narrow it down to the just the broadest qualification (I think `SUBSYSTEM="pci"`), see if that works, then start adding stuff back in.

Comment: It would help if you provided `udevadm info -a` on the device.

Comment: Tried with this much                              SUBSYSTEM=="pci", SYMLINK+="jumanji"                                  but /dev/jumanji was not created

Comment: :/ Instead of restarting via init try `udevadm control --reload-rules`.

Comment: Cross-posted on [Askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/342157/why-doesnt-my-udev-rule-work).

Comment: None of this worked

Comment: Note the S at the end of SUBSYSTEMS. `SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"` might work better.

Answer (score 2):

You need an 'S' at the end of `ATTR` in `ATTR{vendor}` and `ATTR{label}`, and at the end of `SUBSYSTEM`.

An easy mistake to make, I just got burnt myself.